# Lambda Management console, xero API call returns "Error missing token"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, xero-api

I'm running a pilot, whereby I've written a function in aws lambda on console management that should call the accounts and invoices endpoint for the xero demo company, obtain the data and push it to an S3 bucket. However every time I run the function it returns the below

```
"errorMessage": "Missing access token.",
```

Here is my code:

```
def get_xero_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token=None):
    token_url = 'https://identity.xero.com/connect/token'

    # use the refresh token to get a new access token
    if refresh_token:
        headers = {
            'Authorization' : 'Basic ' + base64.b64encode((client_id + ':' + client_secret).encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8'),
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }

        data = {
            'grant_type' : 'refresh_token',
            'refresh_token' : refresh_token
        }

        response =  requests.post(token_url, headers=headers, data=data)
        print(f"Status code: {response.status_code}, Response: {response.json()}")
        return response.json().get('access_token')  # Return access token

    else:  # Initial token request using client_id and client_secret
        client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
        oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client)
        token = oauth.fetch_token(token_url=token_url, client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret)
        return token.get('access_token')  # Return access token


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # Xero credentials
    client_id = '{insert}'
    client_secret = '{insert}'
    refresh_token = '{insert}'

    # Get the OAuth2 token
    token = get_xero_token(client_id, client_secret, refresh_token)
    logger.info(f'Using token: {token}')  # log token usage

    # Create an OAuth2 session
    client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=client_id)
    oauth = OAuth2Session(client=client, token={"access_token" : token})

    # set up S3
    s3 =  boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket_name = 'xerotos3datatransfer'

    # List of Xero API URLs for Invoices and Accounts
    xero_api_urls = [
        'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Invoices',
        'https://api.xero.com/api.xro/2.0/Accounts'
    ]

    # File names for saving data to s3
    file_names = ['xero_invoices_data.json', 'xero_accounts_data.json']

    for url, file_name in zip(xero_api_urls, file_names):
        # Make a request to the Xero API
        response = oauth.get(url)

        # Convert response to JSON
        data = response.json()

        # Push the data to s3
        s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=file_name, Body=json.dumps(data))

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body' : json.dumps('Success!, Data transferred from Xero to s3')
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The idea is to make the API call and push the data from the xero demo company into the S3 bucket. I created the app on xero got the tokens but each time I run the function it returns ""errorMessage": "Missing access token.",